# Form submission in frame

Tags: html, frames

I have a form which has a `target`, and I'd like after submission for only the form to be replaced by the target page, not the whole page. I've wrapped the form in `<frame>` tags but after form submission the whole page is reloaded with the form submission target, not just the form itself (which is contained by frame tags).

Anyway to get the form submission to only replace that frame. Ideally the URL in the browser will not change.

Answer (score 6):

You can use iframe like this. **If you set the iframe as the target of the form the response gets redirected to the iframe**.

> You just have to use iframe's name as the form's target attribute.

```
<form id='myform' action='action.php' method='POST' target='formresponse'>

  <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label><br/>
  <input type='text' name='name' id='name' maxlength="50" /><br/>

  <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label><br/>
  <input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength="50" /><br/>

  <input type='button' name='Submit' value='Submit' />

</form>

<iframe name='formresponse' width='300' height='200'></iframe>
```

http://www.html-form-guide.com/web-form/submit-form-multiple-scripts.html

[MDN Form target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target)

Answer (score 3):

> Try This

```
<form action="your action" target="iframe name">
</form>


<iframe style="display:none" name="iframe name"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

This could work

```
<form action="Action 1 " target="iframe name"></form>
<iframe style="display:none" name="iframe name"></iframe>
```

Let me know what you get